# Get description out of 'Hyperlink or Picture' column in search template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, 2016, managed-property

I have a simple list with a column of type 'Hyperlink or Picture' named 'TestHyperlink'. I've created a Managed Property at the Search Service Application screen for this column so it can be used later inside a Search Template.
I do an index reset and fully crawl to make sure the system is aware of my newly created property.

Inside the Search Template I add the property to the ManagedPropertyMapping tag and create the following line:

```
console.log(ctx.CurrentItem.TestHyperlink)
```

The log shows me the url but not the description. I've read on the Internet it should return a csv value like this: 'url, description' but not in SP2016.

So my question in short; how can i get the description out of a 'Hyperlink or Picture' column in SP2016?

Comment: You don't need to do the index reset. I'll do a test and look for an answer for you.

Comment: That would be very nice of you. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for a concrete answer I've used the following work around. I've split column 'TestHyperlink' into two other columns named 'TestHyperlink_Url' and 'TestHyperlink_Desc' formatted as type 'Text'.
Afterwards I've created a Managed Property for mapping the new columns.
As they are simple text columns it's now possible to use them in my Search Display Template.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
console.log(ctx.CurrentItem["TestHyperlink.desc"]);
```

or also, maybe:

```
console.log(ctx.CurrentItem.TestHyperlink.desc);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't seem to work as 'ctx.CurrentItem.TestHyperlink' isn't an object but just a plain string. Therefore it just return 'undefined'. Maybe I'm choosing the wrong Type format while creating the Managed Property?

Comment: What about `console.log(ctx.CurrentItem["TestHyperlink.desc"]);`?

Comment: Nope same thing 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

Doing my own testing the Managed Property associated with the URL field only stores the URL and throws away the Description. In fact, if I search for the description I don't find it, but if I search for the URL I find that. So that means that during content processing it appears that the URL is the only part that is kept.

Comment: Thanks for your input @matthew-mcdermott Guess my workaround is the solution for my problem.

Comment: I would agree, particularly if you want the description searchable.

Answer (score 0):

You should map your Managed Property to Crawled property **ows_q_URLH_*TestHyperlink***.

Then your managed property will contain URL and description in format: "*Url, Desc*".

Then, in display template you can add some js to extract this url\description:

```
var UrlFull = ctx.CurrentItem.YourManagedProperty;
var UrlPath = (UrlFull .split(','))[0];
var UrlDesc = (UrlFull .split(','))[1];
```

to build hyperlink for example:

```
<div>Link: <a href="_#= $htmlEncode(UrlPath) =#_"> _#= UrlDesc =#_ </a></div>
```